# cURL functions stopped working on WordPress 5.2.4?

Tags: wordpress, php-curl, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm developing a plugin that worked fine with curl_setopt(), curl_init(), curl_exec(), etc functions in WP 5.0.3. After updating to wP 5.2.4, this example of cURL post stopped working (the $api_key is actually set, this is just an example):

```
 $postData = array(
  'some_variables'         => "some_values",
);

 $postDataJSON= json_encode($postData);

 $postDataCURL= curl_init('www.example.com/post/request');                                                 

 curl_setopt($postDataCURL, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
 curl_setopt($postDataCURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postDataJSON);                                                                  
 curl_setopt($postDataCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
 curl_setopt($postDataCURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
      'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',                                                                                
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postDataJSON),
      'x-api-key: ' . $api_key,
    )
  );                                                                                                            

 $postDataResult = curl_exec($postDataCURL);
 curl_close($postDataCURL);
```

Anybody had this kind of issues recently? Also had problem with the GET requests but fixed it with native WordPress functions.

Comment: do you get any error messages on screen or in the event logs?

Comment: That's the main issue, that I don't have a clue of the error. Already activated all the error displays and logs but anything shows up. I'm checking the request results using var_dump and all I get are bools set to false and nulls.

Comment: Could try adding ```curl_getinfo($postDataCURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);``` to see if the issue lies on the api side.  cURL is not a Wordpress function so it's less likely that is the cause.  You might also try making this request in something like Postman as well to see if you are getting proper responses.